# Unity / C# Cycle Through XML Data On Button Press

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to programming and Unity and I am hoping someone can help guide my to a solution.

I have an XML file with data below. I want to display one team's stats at a time and then when the user clicks a button I would like a script to cycle to the next team node in the XML file and display that team's information. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<roster>
    <team>
            <id>0</id>
            <teamname>Atlanta Seagulls</teamname>
            <overall>90</overall>
            <offense>74</offense>
            <defense>98</defense>
    </team>

    <team>
            <id>1</id>
            <teamname>Minnesota Trees</teamname>
            <overall>68</overall>
            <offense>58</offense>
            <defense>73</defense>
    </team>

    <team>
            <id>2</id>
            <teamname>Denver Mountains</teamname>
            <overall>50</overall>
            <offense>39</offense>
            <defense>74</defense>
    </team>
```

Here is what I have for my C# script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

public class LoadXML : MonoBehaviour {

    public TextAsset xmlRawFile;
    public Text uiText;
    public int nodeCount;
    public int index;
    public int teamId;
    public Text teamIdTest;

    // Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    string data = xmlRawFile.text;
    parseXmlFile (data);
}

void parseXmlFile(string xmlData)
{
    string totalVal = "";
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument ();
    xmlDoc.Load (new StringReader (xmlData));
    string xmlPathPattern = "//roster/team";
    XmlNodeList myNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes (xmlPathPattern);
    nodeCount = myNodeList.Count;



    for (int i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++) 
        {
            if (i == index) 
            {

                foreach (XmlNode node in myNodeList) 
                {
                    XmlNode id = node.FirstChild;
                    XmlNode teamname = id.NextSibling;
                    XmlNode overall = teamname.NextSibling;
                    XmlNode offense = overall.NextSibling;
                    XmlNode defense = offense.NextSibling;



                    teamIdTest.text = id.InnerXml;
                    teamId = Int32.Parse (id.InnerXml);

                if (teamId == i) 
                    {

                        totalVal = " Team Name: " + teamname.InnerXml + "\nOverall: " + overall.InnerXml + "\nOffense : " + offense.InnerXml + "\nNodes : " + nodeCount + "\n\n";
                        uiText.text = totalVal;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

}
public void Swap()
{
    if (index < nodeCount - 1) {
        index++;
    } else {
        index = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can for example read file and store each team values in array of XmlNodes. This code can conver node list to array:

```
XmlNode[] nodeArray = myNodeList.Cast<XmlNode>().ToArray();
```

Then when user click button you are selecting next item from array and do your stuff:

```
public void SwapNext()
{
//nodeArray and currentNodeIndex  should be private class variables so you can reach them from all class functions
currentNodeIndex += 1 ;
node = nodeArray[currentNodeIndex];
XmlNode id = node.FirstChild;
XmlNode teamname = id.NextSibling;
XmlNode overall = teamname.NextSibling;
XmlNode offense = overall.NextSibling;
XmlNode defense = offense.NextSibling;

teamIdTest.text = id.InnerXml;
teamId = Int32.Parse (id.InnerXml);

totalVal = $"Team Name: {teamname.InnerXml} Overall {overall.InnerXml} Offense : {offense.InnerXml} Nodes {nodeCount}";
uiText.text = totalVal;
```

You can also parse whole file at once like you do it now and store teams values as object of some class for example class Team and then use array of object Team instead of XmlNode.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for the super fast response. Let me give this a shot. I'm fairly beginner so I'm not 100% sure I will get it working right, but I'm going to try. Thank you!